# Angular 7 app getting CORS error from angular client

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, angular7

I have developed an angular 7 app with express backend. Express running on `localhost:3000` and angular client is running on localhost:4200.

In the `server.js` I have (not the entire code)

```
const app = express();
// Enable CORS
app.use(cors());
// Get our API routes
const api = require('./api');
// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/sfdc-event'));
```

In the api.js file, I have router.get(‘/oauth2/login’) which redirects to https://example.com which sends an access token and authenticates the user (OAuth2 authentication).

When I am calling the url http://localhost:3000/api/oauth2/login everything is working fine, but when I am trying to do the same from angular component.ts -> service.ts I am getting the following error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’
>   missing

Angular app flow as follows login.component.ts which has a button calling a service api.service.ts which executes a http get.

```
login.component.ts

sfdcLogin(): void {
  console.log('DEBUG: LoginComponent: ', 'Login button clicked..');
 this.apiService.login().subscribe( data => { console.log( data ); });
}
```

api.service.ts

```
login() {
  console.log('DEBUG: APiService login(): ', 'login() function.');
  const URL = 'oauth2/login';
  console.log('DEBUG: ApiService login URL : ', `${environment.baseUrl}/${URL}`.toString());
  return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/${URL}`)
    .pipe( map( res => res ));
}
```

Can someone help me get past the error? I have a) CORS b) serving static files from server.js as

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/sfdc-event'));
```

c) dynamic environment variable.
What else I am missing?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: @Arup Sarkar, if applicable kindly mark the correct answer

Answer (score 8):

If this is just for development I recommend using proxy that comes with angular-cli.
Create a file called proxy.json

and

```
{
  "/api/oauth2/login": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000/api/oauth2/login",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

and the call `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.json`. If you expect this to be still a problem in production then we have to have a bigger conversation.

Full documentation:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Also what is CORS exacly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 8):

For Angular 7 you must do other implementation. From angular documentation you must create a proxy.js file:

https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy

Edit the path for your own backend server.

**proxy.js:**

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var proxyConfig = [{
  context: '/api',
  target: 'http://your-remote-server.com:3000',
  secure: false
}];

function setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig) {
  var proxyServer = process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY;
  if (proxyServer) {
    var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer);
    console.log('Using corporate proxy server: ' + proxyServer);
    proxyConfig.forEach(function(entry) {
      entry.agent = agent;
    });
  }
  return proxyConfig;
}

module.exports = setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig);
```

Later add this to your package.json

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.js"
```

And call this with:

```
npm start
```

And in your app.js just simply add:

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
```

I had same problem and that solved my issue. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

To divert all calls for `http://localhost:4200/api` to a server running on `http://localhost:3000/api`, take the [following](https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy) steps.

1. Create a file `proxy.conf.json` in the projects `src/` folder, next to `package.json`.
2. Add the following content to the new proxy file:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "`http://localhost:3000`",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

3. In the CLI configuration file, angular.json, add the proxyConfig option to the serve target:

```
...
"architect": {
    "serve": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
        "options": {
            "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
        },
    ...
    }
}
...
```

4. To run the dev server with this proxy configuration, call `ng serve`.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. That's what I did but I still have an issue with Angular 9 with Express.js
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:7777/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: @DineshKumar I am not the original owner of this answer, I just edited it to have a clear code format, you should ask TiyebM. In any case, I suppose yes, but I did not try.

Comment: Hi, the target is set `"`http://localhost:3000`". Then in QA or PRODUCTION, how to set it? We just have one proxy file.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the callback mechanism to get past the CORS issue, I am utilizing a OAuth flow for the user to get authenticated from https://example.com which was redirecting to https://example.com/auth/callback, I was initiating the request from http://localhost:4200 and then sending the callback url to the server http://localhost:3000 and I was getting the CORS error.

Now, I am redirecting it to the client http://localhost:4200 and got past the CORS problem. All other calls for GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH is from the http://localhost:3000 which is working fine.

Thank you all for your inputs.

Comment: For .net core, check this out: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-cors-consume-web-api-by-mvc-in-net-core-4/

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with **Angular cli** and **.net Framework** in server side.

To solve this problem, I just ennable CORS interaction in server side using the following steps:

1. `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors -Version 5.2.6`

   And then, into WebApiConfig class:
2. Add `using System.Web.Http.Cors;`
3. Inside Register(HttpConfiguration config) method:

> ```
> var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*");
>
> config.EnableCors(cors);
> ```

**or**

> ```
> var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"); //origin, headers, methods
>
> config.EnableCors(cors);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Angular sets some request header parameters out of which one is, 'Content-Type' whose default value is 'application/json'. which when I set to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' resolved the error for me.

Instead of using post method like:

```
this.http.post<any>(requestDetails['url'],requestDetails['data'])
```

First set the request headers using the HttpHeaders Class of Angular like:

```
let reqHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
});
this.http.post<any>(requestDetails['url'],requestDetails['data'],{headers:reqHeaders})
```

refer: https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-and-updating-headers

In my case, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is also set to * for the response headers on the server, to accept requests from any origin (in development case mostly it is: localhost: 4200)

Answer (score 0):

So why we are getting CORS error because we are trying to connect two diffrent domain but possible reason can be a version issue. In my case ,I used angular  proxy and it works perfectly fine .
when we use angular proxy ,it might be a case it will not work because you didn't understand how to use in a perfect manner.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is already answered, but it might help someone who is searching for CORS issue.
You can follow below 3 steps to solve this issue.
1. Create proxy.conf.json file and put it at root level of your app.
2. In package.json file, add proxy parameter in ngstart
3. In angular.json, add proxy file entry.
4. Change all your rest calls to something like /api/getData.

Complete step by step tutorial is given here.
http://www.codeyourthought.com/angular/proxy-to-make-http-call-in-angular/

Answer (score -5):

Since, your angular app is running on 4200 port and backend running on 3000 port, the origin of both the application is different.

To solve this problem, you can setup "nginx" in your machine.

This will make all your requests from angular and backend, go via "nginx" server. Thus, solving the problem of CORS.

Comment: Eventually, this will be hosted on heroku PAAS. I am not sure I can utilize "nginx" server. FYI, I have uploaded the app to heroku and it is the same behavior.

Comment: @ArupSarkar I'm sure there is a CORS header setting in the heroku. Read this article it 10 minutes read and it explaines everything: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS