# How to resole the problem of cors from ionic app

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework

I'm trying to call a free API on Intrenet from an IONIC app, but I faced the problem of CORS here's the error :
`Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful (69406163, line 0)`

I have not Access to the API, because itd a free one from Internet thats why I wonder if its possible to do something in the IONIC App to fix this problem.

Comment: have changed the headers you are sending ? see the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53473754/angular-7-app-getting-cors-error-from-angular-client

Comment: CORS is handled at the server side code

Comment: normally ionic app while running on phone has no origin , so such issues will only exists  when you run in browser. CORS is a security feature at the browser so mobile applications do not have such issues.

Comment: you can append 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' before your Api path